# is a column family placed one next to the other on disk in HBase? another words, is HBase Column-oriented?

Tags: hbase, bigtable, column-oriented, wide-column-store

I'm trying to understand if HBase is a Column-oriented DB.
I understand the structure of one row of HBase - it is divided into column families(which are static and don't change) and each column family can have dynamic number of columns:

```
row: row-key1, familyA:a1 familyA:a2... familyB:b1,familyB:b2,familyB:b3
```

Now it id stated that a column family is stored together on disk. so familyA:a1 familyA:a2 columns of row:row-key1 will be stored together on disk.

But what about familyA:a1 familyA:a2 values in two **different rows**? are they also store one after the other? which would me that HBase is **Column-oriented**.

Everywhere I look I see that HBase is **Wide-Column store**, is it the same as Column-oriented?

Answer (score 4):

Before answering the question, I want to point out one thing about the HBase use case that'll make it easier to understand the HFile layout. HBase (from read workload perspective) is optimized for random key value lookups in really long and wide tables (trillions of rows and millions of columns). It works reasonably well for rowkey prefix based scans too, but it's not built for large single column scans.

That said, HBase is not a truly columnar database, especially when seen as a wide column store too. HBase stores all columns for the same row key and the same column family together. However, different column families are stored in different files which gives the columnar nature to HBase in the sense that you can control configs for each column family independently and you can scan a single column family without worrying about read costs introduced due to columns in other families.
This is how a single HFile looks like (notice that a column is called a *qualifier* in HBase. Also *Type* can be a *Put* or *Delete*):

```
RowKey1:Family1:Qualifier1:Timestamp1:Type:Value
RowKey1:Family1:Qualifier1:Timestamp2:Type:Value
RowKey1:Family1:Qualifier2:Timestamp0:Type:Value
RowKey1:Family1:Qualifier3:Timestamp2:Type:Value
RowKey2:Family1:Qualifier1:Timestamp0:Type:Value
RowKey2:Family1:Qualifier2:Timestamp2:Type:Value
```

Notice that *Qualifier1* is not adjacent for *RowKey1* and *RowKey2*. Instead, all columns for the same row i.e. *RowKey1* key are adjacent.

If you stored every column in its own column family, HBase would become a truly columnar store, but then it would not be able to provide support for millions of columns due to single-row across-columns ACID semnatics that it offers due to its locking strategies to implement that.

**Edit**

Given the above structure of the HFile, the HFile data is actually stored in sorted format based on the following key (Note that one file can have one family only, so, storing the family name in the data itself is somewhat redundant, but there are other uses for that outside the scope of this question):

```
RowKey:Family:Qualifier:Timestamp:Type
```

This sorting order, combined with block level indexes and bloom filters on HFiles makes HBase blazing fast in locating any random *RowKey*, or a *RowKey, Family:Qualifier* tuple, or a *RowKey, Family:Qualifier, Timestamp* tuple.

Comment: Ashu Pachauri - but if columns families are stored one after the other like your example, isn't it optimized for sequential read and NOT random reads?

Comment: @nadavgam I think you mean "columns are stored one after the other" as familes are stored in different files altogether. 
Since columns for the same rowkey are stored together, getting all columns for a single row key is really fast. That's why I said "random Key Value lookups".  Due to block level indexes and bloom filters, along with the rowkey ordered data storage in file, locating a specific rowkey is blazing fast in hbase. Scanning a column, however, is quite slow.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give more details on how random KV lookups are optimized for in HBase.

Comment: I would add that HBase does not handle multiple CFs pretty well, unless the access patterns are very specific. There is a disclaimer on that in HBase guide.